# Is it possible to trigger a custom action on new user with Keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I have a well working Keycloak and a MailChimp account to link. Users should be added with their email to the MailChimp account, once they're added to the Keycloak. What should I do?

I'm using spring boot and token-exchange in the backend to create user accounts, and send back token responses. I wanted to do verification in the backend, but it won't work as expected, as the Keycloak would be joined to another app, which isn't using my backend.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [Event SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_events) (your own code - see [example](https://github.com/metadatacenter/cedar-keycloak-event-listener)), listen to/acquire the event of interest to you and execute your custom "action".

Comment: Thank you so much for your rapid answer. Though I don't understand how to deploy it. I've used the `.bin/jboss` command to add the module to deploy it (I know I can simply add it to `standalone/configuration`) but the result is the same, as the event isn't integrated to the Keycloak. How should I do yet ?

Comment: The command is `./bin/jboss-cli.sh --command="module add --name=com.decimalsnail.keycloak.userlistener --resources=~/Dev/keycloak/user-listener/target/user-listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --dependencies=org.keycloak.keycloak-core,org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi,org.keycloak.keycloak-events-api"`

Comment: Try using an absolute path for `--resources=..` . If that doesn't work, please create a new question and add the JBoss logs.

Comment: The module is being added, I've also imported it in the standalone.xml file as a provider; it's read at startup, but nothing happens on runtime. As if it disappeared.

Comment: When I try adding it to events, I see as logs, that it does not exist.